# pre selected values in listbox from database

Tags: listbox, yii2

I have list box like this

```
$form->field($model, 'user_type_id[]')->listBox($UserTypesArray , array('multiple' => true));
```

where `$UserTypesArray` is the array that holds all the values and names of the list items like this

```
array('1'=>'john' , '1'=>'Doe' , '3' => 'bar')
```

I wanted john and doe to be pre selected when the page loads as they would be the values coming from the database. So I started coding that and ended up writing & finding the following

```
 $data = array('1' => 'John', '2' => 'Doe', '3' => 'foo');
$selected   = array(
  '1' => array('selected' => 'selected'),
  '2' => array('selected' => 'selected'),
);
$htmlOptions = array('size' => '5','multiple' => 'true', 'options' => $selected);
echo $form->field($model, 'user_type_id[]')->listBox($data, $htmlOptions);
```

When I run above code it works without any error but the options of the listbox are not pre selected.

The variable `$data` and `$htmlOptions` will be populated with the real values from the database of which I have completed the code. But as long the above code is not working with static values it wont work with values from database either.

Any one know anything about how to make preselected values in listbox

Comment: Is it many-to-many relation?

Comment: Here is my answer to this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575808/change-the-priority-of-selected-attribute-in-listbox

Answer (score 0):

set attribute first,
for static values in your case

```
    $model->user_type_id =[1,2];
    $form->field($model, 'user_type_id')->listBox($UserTypesArray ,array('multiple' => true));
```