# change the priority of selected attribute in listbox

Tags: html, listbox, yii2

**Following is the example code :**

IN CONTROLLER

```
 foreach($UserTypesArray as $key => $value)
    {
      $model->allowed_users[$key] = ['selected' => 'selected'];
    }
    $model->htmlOptions = array('multiple' => 'true', 'options' =>  $model->allowed_users);
```

IN VIEW

```
$form->field($model, 'user_type_id[]')->listBox($model->all_users ,  $model->htmlOptions);
```

OK here we go!

I have searched a lot on "how to make list box with pre selected values from the database"

Two things happened

1) I ended up writing the above code (which has no issue no error, works perfectly)

2) I found out that in htmlOptions the `selected="selected"` has a low priority so it it gets overwritten and is automatically removed from all `option` tags

further more if I replace `['selected' => 'selected']` with `['disabled' => 'disabled']` it works and all the `option` tags are disabled in the listbox .... As `disabled` has a higher priority so it gets pushed in the `option` tag but the `selected` attribute does not get pushed because of it low priority.

Any one know how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in yii itself I found on one of the yii forums. So I would like to share with you guys.

If you write it like that

```
['selected' => 'selected'];
```

It wont work.

But If you write it like that

```
['selected ' => 'selected']; or true
```

consider the space after selected. `['selected '` If you just put a space after selected it works perfectly.

Don't know why this is. But it works.